# Is "Choosing the right course has been treated by me as a key element in developing my interests" correct?

Tags: prepositions, passive-voice

I want to write a sentence, but without using "I" as a first word.
Is "Choosing the right course has been treated by me as a key element in developing  my interests" correct? Should I put "by me" at the end or any other advises?

Comment: That's okay—but a bit awkward and unnecessarily lengthy. Better, to me, is: *Choosing the right course has been a key element in the development of my interests.* But take a step back. What original sentence did you have in mind (with *I*) and why do you want to avoid starting it with *I*?

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm trying to avoid repetitions. Thank you for your help. I think your version is a bit more clean

Comment: I think the comments here that that sentence is "somewhat clumsy" and "a bit awkward" are being overly polite.  That is a grammatical but terribly awkward and terribly verbose sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat clumsy choice of sentence structure.

The sentence would really sound a lot more natural if you began it with the word "I": "I have treated choosing the right course as a key element ..."

But, if you must use the passive voice ("has been treated"), then the sentence you mention is correctly written. The phrase, "by me" is in the right position. It would not sound good at the very end of this long statement.